# Simple outbound dialing from VOIP to Telephone network

Tags: twilio

I am trying to set up a very simple system where I can dial out to local numbers using a VOIP app or an ATA.

- I have the local number on Twilio
- I have a Sip Domain set up on Twilio
- I have extensions and SIP Devices set up and working
- Using Flow, I can: receive calls, transfer calls to Voicemail, Email and Txt Voicemails

What I cannot seem to figure out is how to just dial outbound calls.  I have been over all the documentation but I am not a coder, and all the blogs on making an outbound call seem to require you to be running a host somewhere other than Twilio.

How do I set this up:

- I pick up any SIP device authenticated to an extension on my SIP domain.
- I dial a local POTS number and it rings that number using my Twilio Local number.
- It all must happen on the Twilio platform (SIP Devices excluded)

I was hoping I could use Twilio flows to do that but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question but it's a bit hard to understand at which point you are stuck. But I'm happy to point you to this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound) which aims for the same result. So you should be able to find the missing pieces in there.